# Installing TensorFlow, where is cuda home on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, tensorflow

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 I have been forced to use the cuda repository which came with Ubuntu due to issues with new security features in the package manager.  I installed cuda using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.  This works for everything else I have been doing.  Unlike the packages provided by nvidia this does not create a cuda directory at `/usr/local/cuda`.  I am now trying to install tensorflow from source and it wants to know where my cuda home directory is.  I am not even sure I have one when using the ubuntu repo.  Do any of you know where it is or how I might get around this issue?

Comment: This is really a Ubuntu specific question and would probably have been better asked in a Ubuntu specific venue

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install CUDA 7.5 in Ubuntu 16.04 with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit` and it was located in `/usr/local/cuda-7.5`

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia doesn't have Cuda 7.5 compatible with Ubuntu 16.04 on their website. I tried their 15.04 version, and it gave me compile errors when trying to build TensorFlow on Ubuntu 16.04. I had to downgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 to make it work. Here's the options they give when trying to download
[image]

Comment: CUDA 8 works for me on Ubuntu but it fails to build with OpenCV and Tensorflow.

Comment: Right, TensorFlow doesn't officially support CUDA 8

Comment: Its too bad though that the configure script requires me to give it my cuda home because everything else worked great with the Ubuntu (not nvidia) provided CUDA 7.5 repo.

Comment: Maybe can purge your Ubuntu cuda, and then run apt-get under strace to see where it puts files. IE, `sudo strace -Ttf -e trace=open apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

Comment: I think I just got it to build with CUDA 8.  I have not tried it yet though.  The following fixed my problem with the BLAS  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2556